# Why does my tflite model predict "Normal" on every image?

Tags: performance-testing, tflite

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the TensorFlow Lite model
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="lite_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                                              rotation_range=5,
                                                              width_shift_range=0.1,
                                                              height_shift_range=0.1)

test_directory = "/kaggle/input/pneumoniadataset/test/"  # Replace with the path to your test dataset
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=test_directory,
    target_size=(SIZE, SIZE),
    class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=1  # Set batch_size to 1 to process one image at a time
)

# Generate predictions using the TFLite model
predictions = []
true_labels = []

# Create a list to store the file names
file_names = []

for _ in range(len(test_generator)):
    images, batch_labels = next(test_generator)  # Get one image and label
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], images)
    interpreter.invoke()
    preds = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    predictions.append(preds[0][0])  # Append the prediction for the single image
    true_labels.append(batch_labels[0])    # Append the label for the single image

    # Append the file name to the list
    file_names.append(test_generator.filenames[test_generator.batch_index - 1])

predictions = np.array(predictions)
true_labels = np.array(true_labels)

# Convert probabilities to classes
predicted_classes = 1 * (predictions > 0.5)

# Confusion matrix
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(true_labels, predicted_classes)
fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=conf_matrix, figsize=(5, 5))
plt.show()

# Print the names of 4 images from each class and predict individually
for class_label in [0, 1]:  # Assuming 0 represents 'normal' and 1 represents 'pneumonia'
    class_indices = np.where(true_labels == class_label)[0]
    print(f"Predictions for Class {class_label}:")
    for i in range(4):  # Print the first 4 images in the class
        index = class_indices[i]
        file_name = file_names[index]
        individual_prediction = "Normal" if predicted_classes[index] == 0 else "Pneumonia"
        print(f"Image: {file_name}, Prediction: {individual_prediction}")

# Check additional individual images
additional_individual_images = [
    "/kaggle/input/pneumoniadataset/test/PNEUMONIA/person1009_virus_1694.jpeg",
    "/kaggle/input/pneumoniadataset/test/PNEUMONIA/person100_bacteria_475.jpeg",
    "/kaggle/input/pneumoniadataset/test/PNEUMONIA/person100_bacteria_479.jpeg",
    "/kaggle/input/pneumoniadataset/test/PNEUMONIA/person100_bacteria_481.jpeg"
]

for image_path in additional_individual_images:
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize((SIZE, SIZE))  # Resize to match the model's input size
    image = np.array(image) / 255.0  # Normalize the image

    # Add an extra dimension for batch size
    input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0).astype(np.float32)

    # Set the input tensor
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_tensor)

    # Run inference
    interpreter.invoke()

    # Get the output tensor
    output_tensor = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

    # Apply softmax to get class probabilities
    class_probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(output_tensor).numpy()[0]

    # Define class labels
    class_labels = ["Normal", "Pneumonia"]

    # Display the results
    print(f"Predictions for {image_path}:")
    for i, (label, prob) in enumerate(zip(class_labels, class_probabilities)):
        print(f"{label}: {prob * 100:.2f}%")
```

and the output is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErzQD.png)

even though it performs well, as you can see in the confusion matrix, but whenever I test it on individual image, it predicts every image as "Normal". I trained this model on efficientnetb0 and converted it into tflite model. I implemented this to develop an android app, but then I saw that it predicted every input image as "Normal". Then, I found out that tflite predicts every image as "Normal" even in python.